# EF6 Code First Change Data Value

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, poco

I'm developing a web application and I'm making queries to my database to bring the information, which I worked correctly, but now something strange is happening.

I have a `CustomerRates` table, which has the following fields:

- Cus_ID
- svCode
- svRateDisc
- svBasicDisc
- svMinCharge
- svFutile
- svWaitingTime
- svWaitingTimeFree

I'm trying to bring data and paint them in a grid, but when I start to carefully review the values ​​do not correspond to those that are in the database, I mean the information brings, but the values ​​change and that only happens when the client ID is the same. This is happening and I don't know why:

Original value (the one in the table):

```
┌───────┬───────┬───────────┬────────────┬────────────┬─────────┬──────────────┬──────────────────┐
│Cus_ID │svCode │svRateDisc │svBasicDisc │svMinCharge │svFutile │svWaitingTime │svWaitingTimeFree │
├───────┼───────┼───────────┼────────────┼────────────┼─────────┼──────────────┼──────────────────┤
│21901  │FLW    │0.4        │5           │7           │12       │0             │0                 │
├───────┼───────┼───────────┼────────────┼────────────┼─────────┼──────────────┼──────────────────┤
│20650  │FLW    │0.4        │5           │7           │12       │0             │0                 │
├───────┼───────┼───────────┼────────────┼────────────┼─────────┼──────────────┼──────────────────┤
│20650  │STD    │0.7        │5.5         │7.5         │15       │0             │0                 │
├───────┼───────┼───────────┼────────────┼────────────┼─────────┼──────────────┼──────────────────┤
│20650  │C250   │1.4        │11          │22          │25       │0             │0                 │
├───────┼───────┼───────────┼────────────┼────────────┼─────────┼──────────────┼──────────────────┤
│20995  │C250   │1.2        │10          │20          │25       │0             │0                 │
├───────┼───────┼───────────┼────────────┼────────────┼─────────┼──────────────┼──────────────────┤
│21371  │FLW2   │0.51       │6.2         │8.5         │10       │0             │0                 │
└───────┴───────┴───────────┴────────────┴────────────┴─────────┴──────────────┴──────────────────┘
```

Value returned me after doing the query:

```
┌───────┬───────┬───────────┬────────────┬────────────┬─────────┬──────────────┬──────────────────┐
│Cus_ID │svCode │svRateDisc │svBasicDisc │svMinCharge │svFutile │svWaitingTime │svWaitingTimeFree │
├───────┼───────┼───────────┼────────────┼────────────┼─────────┼──────────────┼──────────────────┤
│21901  │FLW    │0.4        │5           │7           │12       │0             │0                 │
├───────┼───────┼───────────┼────────────┼────────────┼─────────┼──────────────┼──────────────────┤
│20650  │FLW    │0.4        │5           │7           │12       │0             │0                 │
├───────┼───────┼───────────┼────────────┼────────────┼─────────┼──────────────┼──────────────────┤
│20650  │FLW    │0.4        │5           │7           │12       │0             │0                 │
├───────┼───────┼───────────┼────────────┼────────────┼─────────┼──────────────┼──────────────────┤
│20650  │FLW    │0.4        │5           │7           │12       │0             │0                 │
├───────┼───────┼───────────┼────────────┼────────────┼─────────┼──────────────┼──────────────────┤
│20995  │C250   │1.2        │10          │20          │25       │0             │0                 │
├───────┼───────┼───────────┼────────────┼────────────┼─────────┼──────────────┼──────────────────┤
│21371  │FLW2   │0.51       │6.2         │8.5         │10       │0             │0                 │
└───────┴───────┴───────────┴────────────┴────────────┴─────────┴──────────────┴──────────────────┘
```

The strange thing is that it only happens with this table that the others work correctly.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Is a simple GetAll() and I'm open sql profiler and check the query and is ok

Comment: Without any particular part of code it would be just a long shot, but do you properly dispose your DbContext? This might be EF having some values cached and use them instead of fresh one from the database. But, as I wrote, it's just a guess without actual code...

Comment: The first table's from `show data` when you right click on a table? and second's from your query (linq) ye? I thing that you must to restart your VS, i had something problems a time ago.

Comment: Well, the first table CustomerRate has the real information. and @tdaragon I'm using POCO with EF 6 so this method use Json to organize all. I'm using interface and implementation like this

Comment: public List<CustomerRate> GetAllCustomerRate()
        {
            return new List<CustomerRate>(_customerRateRepository.GetAll());
        }

Comment: where _customerRateRepository is the context (works correctly with other tables), and the call in the controller is this:       public JsonResult GetAllServices()
        {
            var cRates = Facade.CustomerRateAppService.GetAllCustomerRate();
            return Json(cRates, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really I don't know why this error is generated.

My solution was to do a step by step every few methods that were being used to make the call to the monitoring entity.

When I make the map table and define the primary key, the generation of the company is as follows:

`this.HasKey (t => t.Cus_ID);`

Replace it with this:

`this.HasKey (t => t.svCode);`

And bring me the records as it should be ..

Still do not understand why. Thank you very much for your help